# Magento 2: How to edit existing product tab

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, tabs, product-tab

Please guide there are tabs on product page named Details, More information, Reviews. Can you please tell me how to add attributes in these tabs. and please tell me if I want to change tab name "Details" to "Description", "MORE INFORMATION" to "SPECIFICATIONS".

The first tab is for Details in product how to add/edit from admin.

The second tab is for MORE INFORMATION in product how to add/edit attributes from admin.

Comment: U can use translation.

Comment: you can not changes directly from admin. You need to changes by edit file
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: Can you get my answer?

Comment: @ali, Have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Create **catalog_product_view.xml** in your custom theme to change text of existing tab

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Change More Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to change content of tab you need to change template

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
```

and create **attributes.phtml** at

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml